# How to access term positions/offsets from Elasticsearch Painless script?

Tags: elasticsearch

We use AWS Elasticsearch, which support Painless scripting from version 5.
I need an access to [term positions/offsets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html#_term_positions_offsets_and_payloads) in my custom score script.

In old Groovy scripting it worked:

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {"match_phrase": {"text": "life"} },
        "script_score": {
            "script": {
                "lang": "groovy",
                "inline": "termInfo=_index['text'].get('life', _POSITIONS);"
            }
        },
        "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
}
```

But it does not work with Painless. It returns 'compile error'.

Comment: Use groovy instead

Comment: @Val Groovy is disabled in AWS ES

Comment: The AWS Elasticsearch managed service is good enough if you merely want to store your logs, but it's so restrictive that if you need to do anything more involved you should use another provider.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps, I wanted scores based on the position of the query text in the document

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
                {
                    "function_score": {
                        "query": {
                            "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                "field": "query"
                            }
                        },
                        "script_score": {
                            "script": {
                                "lang": "painless",
                                "source": "(params['_source']['field'].toLowerCase().indexOf('query'.toLowerCase())+1)"
                            }
                        },
                        "boost_mode": "max"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```